# Under which conditions are the absolute moments of a random variable finite?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

My question concerns the boundedness of the absolute moments of a random variable $E|X|^k$ for any $0\leq k<\infty$. Or equivalently, under which conditions holds $X\in L^k(\Omega)$

Are there conditions on the probability distribution under which this holds, or holds at least for $k\leq K$ for some $K$?

Does finiteness of all moments or the existence of the moment generating function imply finiteness of absolute moments?

Comment: The moment $E[X]$ exists iff $E|X|<\infty$ by definition of Lebesgue integral. So your last question is unclear. If the moment generating function exists for some interval $-a<t<b$ where $a,b>0$, then $E|X^k|<\infty$ for any $k\geq 0$. 
And for the single $k$, $E|X^k|<\infty$ iff $t^k P(|X|>t)$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that existence of moments of kth order implies finitenett of the kth absolute moment. Just to be sure, this is true for $E|X|^k$ as well instead of $E|X^k|$?

Comment: $E|X^k|=E|X|^k$ since $|X^k|=|X|^k$.

Comment: Thanks. It is much appreciated and answers my question.

Comment: @NCh For any $k>0$, $\mathsf{E}|X|^k<\infty$ iff $t^{k-1}\mathsf{P}(|X|>t)$ is integrable.

Comment: @JGWang Yes, sure, you are right!